# I get an empty page with capybara visit method, but response object has content

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

Ok, so I'm working with capybara + rails 3 + rspect

I'm trying to login to my site, but even though I don't get an error when I use the `fill_in` method, I get an error with the  `click_on` method, since it can't find the element I'm trying to click.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/" class="filter_form" id="login" method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="clearfix login-fields">
              <label for="user_email">Email</label>
              <div class="input login-inputs">
                <input class="input-text" id="user_email" name="user[email]" placeholder="email" size="30" type="email" value="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix login-fields">
              <label for="user_password">Password</label>
              <div class="input login-inputs">
                <input class="input-text" id="user_password" name="user[password]" placeholder="password" size="30" type="password">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input class="btn btn-primary login_btn" id="btn_login" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in">
            <a href="/lms/forgot_password" class="btn">Forgot password...</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn close cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

And here is the test:

```
describe "Login ", js: true, type: :request do
   it "should login correctly if the right credentials are given" do


    Capybara.default_wait_time = 15
    Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false

   visit new_user_session_path
    fill_in 'user_email', :with => 'example@test.com'
    fill_in 'user_password', :with => 'pwd123'
    p page.body
    click_on 'Sign in'
    visit '/'

      save_and_open_page


     response.should have_content('Welcome')
  end
end
```

The worst part is that when I do `p page.body` right before `click_on` I see the following code:

```
<html xmlns=\\\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\\\"><head></head><body></body></html>\
```

But if I change that for `p response.body.inspect` then I get the full html code of the page..., shouldn't the `visit` method load the content of the response on the `page`?

Any help will be appreciated, this is driving me crazy :)

Comment: Is the content of response.body valid html?

Comment: Yes, it's the page I'm visiting...

Comment: No, what I mean is does the HTML pass a validator? Capybara uses Nokogiri to parse the HTML and that might be erroring out. I ask because I see a trailing slash in the HTML you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Add that line:

```
config.include Capybara::DSL
```

to spec/spec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
   .....

   config.include Capybara::DSL

   .....
end
```